# Pureconfig - is it possible to include in conf file another conf file?

Tags: scala, pureconfig

Is it possible to include in ****conf*** file another **conf** file?

Current implementation:

```
// db-writer.conf
writer: {
  name="DatabaseWriter",
  model="model1",
  table-name="model1",
  append=false,
  create-table-file="sql/create_table_model1.sql",
  source-file="abcd.csv"
}
```

Desired solution:

```
// model1.conf + others model2.conf, model3.conf..
table: {
 name="model1",
 table-name="model1",
 create-table-file="../sql/create_table_model1.sql"
}

//db-writer.conf
import model1.conf       <=== some import?
writer: {
  name="DatabaseWriter",
  model="model1",        <=== some reference like this?
  append=false,
  source-file="abcd.csv"
}
```

Reason why I would like to have it like this is :

- to reduce duplicated definitions
- to pre-define user conf file which are rare modified

I guess it is not possible - if not do you have any suggestion how to separate configs & reuse them?

I'm using scala 2.12 lang and pureconfig 0.14 (can be updated to any newer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pureconfig uses [HOCON](https://github.com/lightbend/config) (though some of the interpretation of things like durations differ).  HOCON `include` is supported.

So assuming that you have `model1.conf` in your resources (e.g. `src/main/resources`), all you need in `db-writer.conf` is

```
include "model1"
```

HOCON-style overrides and concatenation are also supported:

```
writer: ${table} {
  name = "DatabaseWriter"
  model = "model1"
  append = false
  source-file = "abcd"
}
```